# Disabled anchor returns enabled using WebElement.isEnabled()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

For some reason `elmFinder.isEnabled()` resolves to `true` even on disabled html anchor tags.

I've setup a [test site to prove this](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/oExtzK/).

The following Protractor test fails when IMHO shouldn't

```
describe('isEnabled() should resolve to true on any html element', function() {
  var checkElm = element(by.model('checked'));
  var btnElm = element(by.model('button'));
  var linkElm = element(by.model('link'));

  it('open test page', function() {
    browser.get('http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/oExtzK/');
  });

  it('should be enabled by default: button & link', function() {
    expect(btnElm.isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(linkElm.isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('clicks the checkbox to switch enabled/disabled status', function() {
    checkElm.click();
  });

  it('button should now be disabled', function() {
    expect(btnElm.isEnabled()).toBeFalsy();
  });

  // This fails
  it('link should now be disabled', function() {
    expect(linkElm.isEnabled()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Output:

```
Describe: isEnabled() should resolve to true on any html element
 001 - open test page ✔
 002 - should be enabled by default: button & link ✔
 003 - clicks the checkbox to switch enabled/disabled status ✔
 004 - button should now be disabled ✔
 005 - link should now be disabled  FAILED!
   Message:    Expected true to be falsy.
   Stacktrace: Error: Failed expectation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it at [java bindings docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled())

> will generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.

So I figured, workaround is using + negating `elm.getAttribute('disabled')` instead of `elm.isEnabled()`

```
it('link should now be disabled', function() {
  expect(linkElm.getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
});
```